# rsync Module error

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, rsync

I have a rsync server and i can not list modules or transfer to modules.

**Following work correctly:**

```
rsync -v test.txt user@host.com:test
```

It will be create a new file "test" in the home directory of user

**Following don't work correctly:**

```
rsync -v test.txt user@host.com::moduleA
```

and

```
rsync server@host.com::
```

It returns this:

```
> rsync: failed to connect to host.com (*inet_ntop failed*):
> Connection refused (111) rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at
> clientserver.c(122) [sender=3.0.8]
```

On the server (with ssh) execute  "rsync localhost::" returns the module list. But execute the command with the hostname it will be the same error as above.

Can anyone help? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with this command `rsync -azve"ssh -l user" --rsync-path="sudo rsync"  file.txt user@host::module`

The reason was the option `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`

Answer (score 2):

rsync server uses its own protocol (on port 873) for the connection, not ssh.  If you're only allowing ssh for the rsync transport, it's not going to work.  Is your firewall blocking port 873?

Note that if you're doing this across the Internet, you'll want to secure this traffic.  You can use a VPN or set up the remote shell connection using the `--rsh` option.  For the latter, take a look at:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

And go to the "Using Rsync-daemon Features Via a Remote-shell Connection" section.  Basically, run:

`rsync -v test.txt --rsh=ssh user@host.com::moduleA` or possibly `rsync -v -e "ssh -l user" test.txt user@host.com::moduleA` (since the `user@host.com::moduleA` will auth against the rsync user, not the ssh user)

Comment: Thanks, but i have always try to connect with -e ssh etc.. with the same problems.  
But why work the command when i connect without modules?

Comment: rsync defaults to ssh if you are not using rsync server.  If you specify modules, then you're using rsync server, and the transport is not ssh in that case.

Comment: ok i understand. But the server runs correct because i can list modules on the server (localhost) Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, if you're on the server (localhost), you're just connecting over the rsync protocol on port 873 and you're just using the loopback interface.  If you're connecting to it from a remote host, either you have to open port 873 in the firewall (and have unencrypted traffic on the Internet), or you have to configure a VPN, or you have to specify the remote shell for the transport.

Comment: Ok i have to connect rsync with ssh, i use this command `rsync -e "ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -l user" user@host::`
But it don't work. Connect with ssh only, works perfect ( `ssh host` )

Comment: Have you tried `rsync -e "ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -l user" host::` ?  Remember that the ssh user is not the same as the rsync user when you use rsync daemon, and that you said `rsync localhost::` worked (in the localhost connection, you are not specifying a user).  What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that it gave this error because my receiving directory had spaces in the name.  So "My Directory" did not work as a receiving directory.  Once I changed this to "My_Directory", the errors went away.